# Get Actual Character from ISO-8859-1 Character

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a text:

```
&Aacute; example link.
```

In **ISO-8859-1** `&Aacute;` is `Á`.

Now I am trying to convert that `&Aacute;` to `Á` using following code:

```
Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(text.getBytes());

CharBuffer data = iso88591charset.decode(inputBuffer);

ByteBuffer outputBuffer = utf8charset.encode(data);
byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();
return new String(outputData);
```

But it doesn't converting that `&Aacute;` to `Á`.

Is the any way to achieve this?

Also I want to know, given a String can we determine which Charset is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have confused character encodings (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1...) with HTML Character Entities (`&Aacute;`, `&Ouml;` et.c.).

Check out the [unescapeHtml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) function of Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html), I assume it will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. This what I want.